# Ruby SequelGem Can't figure out to set fields for DB that already exists

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I have a DB table called Agents how do I get Sequel to let me talk to it?

The table already exists but nothing I've done seems to work.

Heres the Model:

```
class Agents < Sequel::Model(:agents)
  set_primary_key :id
  one_to_many :branches
end
```

I thought I had to run the create table method so here's that to:

```
DB.create_table? :agents do
    primary_key :id
    integer :office_count, null: false, default: 0
    text :name
    text :website
    text :main_office_city
    text :main_office_post_code
    boolean :sales
    boolean :lettings
    boolean :lettings_and_sales
end
```

but when I try to do this:

```
a = Agents.create(name: "test")
a.save
```

I just get:

```
`block in set_restricted': method name= doesn't exist (Sequel::MassAssignmentRestriction)
```

The error happens regardless if the `create_table?` block is executed or not.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is name an actual column because your create_table does not show it

Comment: It is an actual column and yes I forgot to put it in the `create_table?` block but adding it makes no difference.

Comment: Drop the table completely and try again your block will only create a table if it doesn't exist so adding name to that block now will have no impact

Comment: Why do I have to go through the whole process of creating a table? Isn't there a way to do this without having to do that? Just, dropping a table doesn't seem like it's the right way to do it.

Comment: If this table already exists with a column called name then your database connection is wrong. If it does not have a column called name then you will need to modify the table using `DB.add_column` if it does not exist then just change your `DB.create` to include `name`. That error directly correlates to the lack of a name column in the agents table for the database you are connected to.  For additional assistance  [Review the documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/)

Comment: Also in standard convention the class should be called `Agent` (singular) [Read More Here](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#sequel-models)

Comment: I thought you named it the same as the table? which is called Agents

Comment: conventionally speaking a Model represents 1 row in a table so the table represents all the "agents" and a Model represents a single "agent". This also allows for the model to infer the table name e.g. Model name Agent infers table name agents. but since you explicitly named your table via `class Agents < Sequel::Model(:agents)` this is not specifically your issue see my other comments

Comment: I see, well regardless I think there's enough information to fix my issue so thanks!